# Bash switch case statement keeps failing to parse arguments, but pattern matching looks fine?

Tags: bash

I am studying a simple bash script, or what I thought would be simple. It looks as though it is simply trying to store the first argument as a variable before proceeding.

However, it fails every time.

Script:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
      variableName=*)
      variableName="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "***************************"
      echo "* Invalid argument:"
      echo "* ($1)"
      echo "***************************"
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
done
```

Now, if I try to execute it, this happens:

```
$ sh script.sh "test"
***************************
* Invalid argument:
* (test)
***************************
```

The pattern match is `*`, so that looks like it should match anything. At that point, it should simply be storing the variable, and that's it.

In the non-dissected script, there are other variables being stored which proceed this one, hence the loop.

Comment: The pattern is not `*`, it's `variableName=*`; since the first argument doesn't start with "variableName=", it's not going to match.

Comment: Well documented first question! Keep posting and good luck to all!

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code with the argument `variableName=xx` it will not go into the Invalid argument condition.
Add a `echo foo` in the line above the `;;` and you will see this.

In the end of the script, the variable `variableName` will be set to the value you passed in, i.e. `xx` in this case.

The following snipped is your code plus some echo statements which hopefully clearly show, what's going on.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
      variableName=*)
      variableName="${1#*=}"
      echo "setting variableName to $variableName"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "***************************"
      echo "* Invalid argument:"
      echo "* ($1)"
      echo "***************************"
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
done

echo "variableName is set to $variableName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is `variablename=*`, not `*`. Your argument doesn't start with `variablename=`, so that case fails.